# MSTest Environment.CurrentDirectory incorrect VS 2012

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, mstest

I am using MSTest and Visual Studio 2012 for unit testing and am encountering a difference in how it runs on two different machines with regards to Environment.CurrentDirectory calls. Both machines are running the exact same tests and using the exact same .testsettings file (with all deployment turned off) yet on one the Environment.CurrentDirectory returns the bin/debug of the project (like I want) and the other returns the TestResults/.../Out as the current working directory.

In the one that runs in the bin/debug folder the TestResults folder for the run is empty but on the other machine the TestResults folder has an AgentReset file in it and I don't know where it came from. Does anyone know why this would be occurring and if there is a config or setting somewhere where?

Comment: I also have the same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have any deployments that are turning on on the second machine.